# Underscore prefix on member variables. intellisense

Tags: c#, coding-style, naming-conventions

everyone said the "underscore, no underscore" debate is purely philosophical and user preference driven but with intelli-sense having the underscore allows you to differentiate your member variables from your local variable very easily and thus giving you a concrete benefit

is there any counter argument to this benefit of having underscores to all member variables?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes - for some people it reduces readability. I believe different people read in different ways (some internally vocalise and others don't, for instance). For some people (myself included) underscores interrupt the "flow" of code when I'm reading it.

I'd argue that if you're having difficulties telling local and instance variables apart, then quite possibly either your methods are too big or your class is doing too much. That's not always going to be the case of course, but I don't tend to find it a problem at all with short classes/methods.

Comment: I am going to refer anyone who thinks that underscore prefix is a good idea to this answer.

Comment: well, i've always been using underscore.. for me this. 1) more typing 2) easy to ommit accidentally 3) underscore is easier to read (from my point of view) because this. is more like vb "then" "end if" 4) and no matter how small or big your method is, it's always beneficial to clearly differentiate among local and class vars

Comment: @Jack0fshad0ws: It's a matter of taste, certainly. Personally it adds too much flow-breaking punctuation for me. I wasn't suggesting adding `this.` everywhere though - I just don't differentiate with syntax or a prefix. I can't remember the last time I was even slightly confused between local and instance variables. Keeping methods short and choosing names well makes it pretty clear whether you're dealing with transient information of logical object state.

Comment: Not only _do my _brain have _to pause at every _ _trying to _figure out if _it's a control _character (reading _sanely named variable _names is _kind _of _automatic like reading whole _words in a book without even looking _at the single _characters _- but the _ also indents variables by _1 character, breaking indentation flow 'causing an irregular vertical _outlining _;p

Comment: I'm not even going to read your comment Oskar.

Answer (score 13):

If it's just the intellisense you want you can always get it by typing "`this.`".

OK, it's 4 more chars than "_", but the intellisense will then bring up your members for you.

If you use underscores and your team uses underscores then keep using them. Others will use "`m`_", others might have other ideas. I use StyleCop and on my team the debate is over,  we use "`this`." and Hungarian style or underscore prefixes are not used. And we just don't worry about it anymore.

[Edit] This is not a criticism of your question - it's a valid question and it's worth asking - but this debate wastes way too much time on dev projects. Even though I don't like everying about StyleCop I willingly use it as it cuts out this type of debate. Seriously, I've been in hour long meetings where this kind of discussion occupies a whole dev team. Crazy. Like I say, your question is valid but please don't waste your own time agonising over this, it's not worth it:-)

Comment: +1 I agree - if you can shortcut the debate then do so.

Comment: Plus I think `this.` improves readability. With syntax highlighting it also makes it easier to spot private variables at a glance.

Answer (score 7):

Using underscore is just one way of achieving that effect. The important thing is to be consistent about it.

Comment: and not even Microsoft is consistent in the .NET Framework... ;)

Answer (score 5):

The underscore can be seen as a form of hungarian notation`*`, but the prefix is a "magical character" instead of something that has a meaning.

If you want something that says more about what the prefix is for, you would use a prefix like `member` or `mbr` or `m`. Sometimes the prefix `m_` is used, but then the underscore is used as a separator rather than a part of the prefix, and the naming recommendations for .NET says that it shouldn't be used as a separator.

Personally I have come to like the underscore for member variables, eventhough it's a prefix with a hidden meaning. It doesn't clutter up the names as much as any other prefix would.

And as always, it's more important to pick a standard and stick to it, than which standard it is that you actually pick.

---

`*` Hungarian notaition has mostly come to be used to specify data type in weakly typed languages like VBScript, but the original intention was to specify other properties of variables, so using it for member variables is more along the original intentions.

Answer (score 4):

Using this. everywhere reduces readability in my opinion.  Underscore prefixes for private class fields is perfectly acceptable.  Its hardly Hungarian which is a truly awful naming convention and on the intellisense front typing _ plus a letter is an extremely quick way to bring up your list.
I use CSLA.NET and a lot of the BO examples use the underscore convention and I continue to use it in all my work.  Don't let the old school ex C++ and C developers scare you into thinking it isn't good practice - .NET doesn't suffer the same issues.  A good example is passing arguments in constructors:

```
public MyObject(int field1, int field2, int field3)
{
    _field1 = field1;
    _field2 = field2;
    _field3 = field3;
}
```

In my opinion is a lot more readable than

```
public MyObject(int field1, int field2, int field3)
{
    this.field1 = field1;
    this.field2 = field2;
    this.field3 = field3;
}
```

But it is personal taste and as has been said elsewhere consistency is the most important issue.

Answer (score 3):

It really doesn't matter what naming convention you choose as long as you use it in whole project.

Comment: I believe it *does* matter. If you have a naming convention where every member of every kind starts with the project name, for instance, you end up with a huge amount of cruft and code which is hard to read. Consistency is certainly very important, bit it's not the *only* important thing.