# object names starting with underscore

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am going through a tutorial on MVC - Linq to SQL. Here, I noticed they are using underscore in object names (first character in object name) such as "_dataContext"

Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
         public class MovieRepository : IMovieRepository
         {
              private MovieDataContext _dataContext;

              public MovieRepository()
              {
                    _dataContext = new MovieDataContext();
              }

              #region IMovieRepository Members

              public IList<Movie> ListAll()
              {
                   var movies = from m in _dataContext.Movies
                        select m;
                   return movies.ToList();
              }

              #endregion
         }
     }
```

My questions is, what is the purpose of using this underscore?

Comment: Related reading: [Underscore prefix on member variables. intellisense](http://stackoverflow.com/q/833811)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> My questions is, what is the purpose of using this underscore?

No technical purpose.  This is merely a convention used by some people to designate private fields.  It is completely optional, and merely a style choice.

Comment: The best advantage I've found to it is that intellisense/debugging windows are sorted so all the backing fields appear in one place together.  The worst advantage I've found is its ability to provoke heated debates about coding style.

Comment: @HansJonus I agree - coding style is very personal.  I, personally, use lower camel case, but only because StyleCop will enforce this, and having a tool helps guarantee project consistency.  However, there is no technical reason to use any convention here.

Answer (score 1):

Underscores by convention signify a private member, but have no actual effect. Also, any non-private members that start with underscore will throw a compiler warning.

Answer (score 1):

It's so you don't have to come to stack overflow, to explain why this gives you a stack overflow

```
private int someValue;

public int SomeValue {get {return someValue; } set {SomeValue = value;}}
```

Names differing just by case, don't like it...

Answer (score 0):

That's basically to allow at-a-glance distinguishing between class level fields and local variables and method parameters.

Answer (score 0):

To delineate private instance variables from other types of fields.  It is a convention; there is no semantic value.

BTW, the "official" MS C# programming guidelines suggest camel case for private class variables.  The decision is up to you and your team, but personally I don't like it because the names will often conflict with method parameters.  I use the underscore myself, but again, use whatever works best for you and other maintainers of the code.  The only hard rule is to be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this used in projects where programmers had a VB.NET background: as VB is mostly case insensitive this will help distinct between fields and properties (i.e. it's a coding convention to indicate private fields, I'd think).

VB programmers would write:

```
Public Class Princess
  Private _pretty
  Public ReadOnly Property Pretty As Boolean
      Get
          Return _pretty
      End Get
  End Property
End Class
```

Whereas C# programmers may write

```
public class Princess 
{
  private bool pretty;
  public bool Pretty { get { return pretty; } }
}
```

Note that in both cases these kind of princesses by default would be ugly.

Comment: Bit strong isn't it, calling me a VB programmer!. :D

Comment: C# programmers wouldn't put a brace ({) on the same line

Comment: @MyKuLLSKI agreed, did that mainly to make the sample code a bit more concise. Feel free to edit it though!